# Input type = "text" name did not shown in print preview

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, printing

I have seem the similar question, why `input-type="text"` name did not working in print preview. SO, I try to print this project, but input-type="text" won't work. Anyone know how to solve this? I have see many solutions and won't work and I try in other browsers and won't work too.

This is the out put after I print preview.
[print preview which data is input-type="text"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEhtH.png)

This is the code

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="student_session_id[]" value="<?php echo $row->student_session_id ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="semester[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="evaluation_period[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="surah[]" value="<?php echo $row->surah ?>" class="form-control" required>
<input type="text" name="score[]" value="<?php echo $row->score ?>" class="form-control" required>
<input type="text" disabled value="<?php echo $row->predicate ?>">
```

This is the data
[data which I want to print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2HFm.png)

Anyone how to solve so the data from `input type="text"` is shown on print preview?

Comment: These textboxes shown fine in print preview - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/esnyu729/ . Judging by your screenshot, you have quite a complicated CSS theme...so maybe there is some print-specific CSS which sets them to be hidden in print mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add custom CSS to overwrite your current CSS.
If it's ok, you might find somewhere in the site css which hide the textbox when printing.

```
<style>
@media print {
   input[type="text"] { display: block !important; }
}
</style>
```